# My discord bot doesn't reply to my message

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

```
import discord
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
TOKEN = "MY TOKEN HERE"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user.name} has logged in!")

async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "안녕?":
        await message.send("안녕!", reference=message)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

This is my code.
And I want my discord bot to reply to my message, but it does not reply to my message.
What's wrong with my code?

Please fix this please.
Im working on this problem for 2 days.
And I can't find the answer.

ps.i'm using Macbook. (is there any difference between making a discord bot on Mac or Windows?)

Comment: You need to enable message_content intents.

Comment: thank you so much! I just searched how to enable message_content intents and it works. have a good day.~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, where you defined client, you need to give it a prefix, which is the special character you can mention it with. So like this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Then you get the `on_ready` event right. Moving on to the commands. You need another import which is:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

After that you can create your first command:

```
@client.command()
async def myfirstcommand(ctx:commands.Context):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}!")
```

And you can trigger it by typing `!myfirstcommand` in the chat. However I see that you want to trigger it by an event. You can do that too:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.content.lower() == "hi":
        await message.channel.send(f"Hello {message.author.mention}!")
```